# WebRTC - create PeerConnectionFactory object

Tags: android, webrtc

i previously used WebRTC `1.0.22672`, now i switched to last version `1.0.26885`.
previously i used this code to create PeerConnectionFactory And VideoSource Object and it worked fine:

```
PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
                    .createInitializationOptions();
    PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

    //Create a new PeerConnectionFactory instance - using Hardware encoder and decoder.
    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
    DefaultVideoEncoderFactory defaultVideoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
            rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),  /* enableIntelVp8Encoder */true,  /* enableH264HighProfile */true);
    DefaultVideoDecoderFactory defaultVideoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
    peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory(options, defaultVideoEncoderFactory, defaultVideoDecoderFactory);


    //Now create a VideoCapturer instance.
    VideoCapturer videoCapturerAndroid;
    videoCapturerAndroid = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(false));


    //Create MediaConstraints - Will be useful for specifying video and audio constraints.
    audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

    //Create a VideoSource instance
    if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
        videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid);
    }
```

but in latest version i have two errors on `new PeerConnectionFactory...`
that says:

> 'PeerConnectionFactory(long)' is not public in 'org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

and on `peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource...`

that syas:

> createVideoSource
>   (boolean)
>   in PeerConnectionFactory cannot be applied
>   to
>   (org.webrtc.VideoCapturer)

How can i solve these errors?

and can someone tell my WHY there is no documentation or change-log for android native WebRTC?!

Comment: How did you get rootEglBase ?

Comment: @JaswantSingh by `rootEglBase = EglBase.create();`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How can i solve these errors?

There are many APIs has been deprecated or removed from WebRTC newest version. Please do the following steps to resolve those errors.

**Step 1:** Change your code from

```
peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory(options, defaultVideoEncoderFactory, defaultVideoDecoderFactory);
```

to

```
peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
        .setOptions(options)
        .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
        .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
        .createPeerConnectionFactory();
```

**Step 2**: Change your code from

```
//Create a VideoSource instance
if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
    videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid);
}
```

to

```
//Create a VideoSource instance
if (videoCapturerAndroid != null) {
    SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
    videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid.isScreencast());
    videoCapturerAndroid.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, getApplicationContext(), videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
}
```

> Can someone tell my WHY there is no documentation or change-log for
>   android native WebRTC?

The change log is at

https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+log

**Note:** About your problems, you can follow the below link for more details.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/gwJP5Sf0cdE